# Write data to mtd and mtdblock

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, flash-memory

I'm trying to write data to MTD device like this topic: [Write on a mtd block device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336285/write-on-a-mtd-block-device)

But when I use `/dev/mtd0`, I just read right first byte, another byte still 0xFF, like:

```
MTD Type: 3
MTD total size: 200000 bytes
MTD erase size: 1000 bytes
buf[0] = 0xde
buf[1] = 0xff
buf[2] = 0xff
buf[3] = 0xff
...
buf[18] = 0xff
buf[19] = 0xff
```

When I use `/dev/mtdblock0`, this working right.

```
MTD Type: 10
MTD total size: befcfb60 bytes
MTD erase size: 0 bytes
buf[0] = 0xde
buf[1] = 0xad
buf[2] = 0xbe
buf[3] = 0xef
...
buf[18] = 0xbe
buf[19] = 0xef
```

Furthermore, when I check flash content by `hexdump /dev/mtd0 -n64 -C` and `hexdump /dev/mtdblock0 -n64 -C` then the contents of both are same.

Final purpose is use /dev/mtd0 not mtdblock, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was researched and realize this issue occurs due to my flash device

```
flash: flash@0 {
    compatible = "sst,sst25vf016b", "jedec,spi-nor";
    spi-max-frequency = <50000000>;
};
```

I saw where performing multi-byte writes to a SST25VF016B would fail.
To fix it, we can fix the application from write multi-byte to write every byte like:

```
lseek(fd, 0x150000, SEEK_SET);
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    result = write(fd, writedata[i], sizeof(writedata[i]));
```

Or we can fix into kernel with reference patches at: https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200911144703.25409-2-m.felsch@pengutronix.de/T/